# No. Pattern print

Tags: java

How to print this pattern

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9
```

I tried to do this way

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    for (int j = i; j <= i + 2; j++) {
        System.out.print(j);
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

But, it gave me this output

```
1 2 3 
2 3 4 
3 4 5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this. This is OK.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
        System.out.print(3*(i-1) + j);
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Why does it work?

Well ... if you watch carefully, you see that
on row `i`, you have these 3 numbers:

`3*(i-1)+1`, `3*(i-1)+2`, `3*(i-1)+3`

(the last number is the one divisible by 3).

So that's your general formula.

Comment: @Thank you Sir, for explaining the algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

When working with 2d arrays, drink rc cola, or play with an rc toy. It'll help you remember Row then Column.

You need to fix your second array so that it adds up to the numbers you want.

Like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
        System.out.print((3*i)+j);
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: But, the second row now starts from 3. The output is as follows, 1st row 123, 2nd row 345, 3rd row 567

Comment: @AjayKumar yeah, rushed this answer a little bit, peter's got the right algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that everytime you are entering to the first for you are reseting the variable j.

So the sifrs, second and thirt time you got the right answer, but on the forth j is reseting, so what you have to do is the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int j;
    int k = 1;
   for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
for (j = i; j <= i + 2; j++) {
    System.out.print(k);
    System.out.print(" ");
    k++;
}
System.out.println();
}
}
```

Adding a new constant k that stores the number of iterations and printing them as you want. Hope it helps!

Comment: Your two nested loops could well be e.g. `for (int i = 1001; i <= 1003; i++)` and same for j. That's because you don't use the i and j for any output value you print out. You use them only for counting 3x3=9. And the k you just keep incrementing it. Interesting approach. +1 from me ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
    if(i%3==1){
        System.out.println();
    } 
    System.out.print(i);
    System.out.print(" "); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) implementation of the problem:

```
IntStream.range(0, MAX)
         .forEach(i -> IntStream.rangeClosed(1, MAX)
                                .mapToObj(j -> j == MAX ? 
                                               String.format("%3d", i * MAX + j) + "\n" :
                                               String.format("%3d", i * MAX + j) + "  ")
                                .forEach(System.out::print)
                 );
```

The value for `MAX` in this case will be `3`.

Output for `MAX = 5` -

```
  1    2    3    4    5
  6    7    8    9   10
 11   12   13   14   15
 16   17   18   19   20
 21   22   23   24   25
```